# Sequence of tences

Tags: tense, backshifting

Should you say me which is correct?

> Our teacher said the place where we were going to stay **IS** supposed to have beautiful paysages.
>
> Our teacher said the place where we were going to stay **WAS** supposed to have beautiful paysages

Comment: The correct spelling is "tenses". Also, I guess you meant to say "... supposed to have beautiful landscapes/views".

Comment: Both constructions are possible, but in this context 'said that it is' makes more sense. The reputation of the area for beautiful landscape is ongoing. (_Paysage_ is not an English word.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll note that by *paysages* you probably mean the French word, which is *landscapes* in English. I'm going to use that word instead.

---

> "Our teacher said the place where we were going to stay ***is*** supposed to have beautiful landscapes."

This might be said after their reservation was cancelled. It still *does* have beautiful landscapes—but they aren't going to stay there anymore.

> "Our teacher said the place where we were going to stay ***was*** supposed to have beautiful landscapes."

This might be said after there was a terrible fire. It *did* have beautiful landscapes—but it doesn't anymore.

---

Generally speaking, if it's a fact that it still does have beautiful [landscapes], then the present tense would be used; if it's no longer a fact (or never was a fact—perhaps the teacher was lying or mistaken), then the past tense would be used.

So, it's a matter of context. It depends on the current situation at the time the sentence is spoken.

Comment: thank you so much